# Black Dots when shooting video on Nikon D5300 manual settings

Tags: video, nikon-d5300

after i shoot videos for a few minutes these black dots appear on my video. I am aware that my Nikon is mainly a photography camera but i am not sure why this keeps happening when i shoot video

https://youtu.be/rfrv39zwn7Y?t=6 in this youtube video that i shot , the lines appear on the white paper on which the drawing in drawn(just click to open it at the time stamp)

[image: they look like flashing black dotted lines]

Comment: It certainly appears that there are black dots such as you describe in your example image. What is your question for us?